# Echoing aliases into a .bashrc file

Tags: linux, shell, alias, bashrc

I want to echo an alias straight into my `.bashrc` file. Here is what I am using:

```
echo alias cdear='cd | clear' >> .bashrc
```

However, the new line in `.bashrc` does not contain the quote marks.

I would also like this to go at the end of .bashrc with a line break from the last line.

How can I change my command in order to:

1. ensure the quote marks are retained?
2. ensure the alias is added to the end of the file with a line break?

Answer (score 10):

Surround the content of `echo` with double quotes. To get a newline *before* the new alias, use `echo -e` and insert a newline `\n`:

```
echo -e "\nalias cdear='cd | clear'" >> .bashrc
```

Comment: That works flawlessly. I should have thought to contain the entire command in quotes that way. Thank you.

Comment: @user328721: If an answer actually answers your question, you should mark it as accepted.