# How to add alias to .bashrc via shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, bashrc

I would like to append a command alias to a .bashrc file via script. However, I got confused when it comes to escaping it. 
The alias is simple:

```
logtee() {
    tee -a "${SCENARIO_LOG_FOLDER:?'empty_log_folder'}/$1"
}
```

I've seen [answers to similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/762738/echoing-aliases-to-bashrc), but `echo -e` doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape " and $ in your content:

```
echo -e "logtee() {
    tee -a \"\${SCENARIO_LOG_FOLDER:?'empty_log_folder'}/\$1\"
}" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: yep, that works. thanks. can you suggest some article I can read on escaping? or man page?

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting